# Создаю тест на php

Tags: php, post

Нужно сделать так чтобы вопросы появлялись по очереди после того как пользователь ответит

index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$questions = [
    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 1',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 0
    ],

    [
      'question' => 'Question 2',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 1
    ],

    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 3',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 2
    ],

    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 4',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 3
    ],

    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 5',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 4
    ],

];


?>

<form action="/rec.php" method="post">
  <?php 
    echo $questions['0']['question'];
  ?>
  <input type="text" name="answer">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Дальше">
</form>
```

rec.php

```
<?php


if($_POST['answer']==$questions[0]['valid']){
     echo 'Правильно сделал';
}
print_r($_SESSION['test']);

#print_r($_POST);
echo $_POST['answer'];
?>
```

rec.php выдает такие ошибки

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: questions in /home/aldoniq/CodeGuru/test.com/rec.php on line 3**

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /home/aldoniq/CodeGuru/test.com/rec.php on line 6**

*Важно: я не прошу сделать за меня.
Опишите пожалуйста что можно сделать,
что прочитать чтобы решить это.
сижу уже неделю
Все что я сделал за неделю я скинул сверху*

Comment: В смысле вы не можете перевести текст ошибки?

Comment: Подозреваю что вам надо прочитать и осознать http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke. В частности rec.php и index.php исполняются независимо и переменные объявленные в индексе в req.php не существуют.

Comment: @AlexeyTen  то есть мне нужно переменную $questions продублировать  в rec.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как я создал тест

*Исправьте в комментариях если думаете что можно сделать лучше. Кажется сделал костыльно*

Файл index.php

```
session_start();

$questions = [
    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 1',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 0
    ],

    [
      'question' => 'Question 2',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 1
    ],

    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 3',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 2
    ],

    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 4',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 3
    ],

    [ 
      'question' => 'Question 5',
      'answers' => [ '1' , '2' , '3','4', '5'],
      'valid' => 4
    ],

];

$_SESSION['questions'] = $questions;

if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])){
  $test = [
    'current' => '0',
    'answer' => []
  ];
} else {
  $test= $_SESSION['test'];
}


$_SESSION['test'] = $test;

if($_SESSION['test']['current']=='5'){
  echo 'Вы закончили тест';
  // unset cookies
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
  }
}
  die;
}
?>

<form action="/rec.php" method="post">
  <?php 
    echo $questions[$test['current']]['question'];
  ?>
  <input type="text" name="answer">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Дальше">
</form>
```

Файл обработчик rec.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_POST['answer']==$_SESSION['questions'][$_SESSION['test']['current']]['valid']){
     $_SESSION['test']['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];
     $_SESSION['test']['current']++;
}

print_r($_SESSION['test']);

#print_r($_POST);
header ('Location: /');
?>
```